# Why even if unchecked disabled the script in the editor it keep working and make object/s to be interactable/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is a bit long maybe I should remove all the variables in the top ? The script give the user the option to interact with objects. But even if I uncheck disable the script in the editor and then running the game I can interact with the object the script is attached to.

Only if I remove the script from the object in the editor first then running the game then it will not be interactable.

What make the script to be working even if unchecked ?

Maybe the problem is in the FPEInteractableBaseScript script since FPEInteractableActivateScript is type of FPEInteractableBaseScript ?

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class FPEInteractableActivateScript : FPEInteractableBaseScript
    {

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If true, player can interact with this while holding something. If false, they cannot.")]
        protected bool canInteractWithWhileHoldingObject = true;

        [Header("Inventory Item Requirements (Optional)")]
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If true, activation will require an inventory item with the parameters as configured below")]
        private bool requireInventoryItem = false;
        public bool RequireInventoryItem { get { return requireInventoryItem; } }

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("The type of inventory item required to activate")]
        private FPEInventoryManagerScript.eInventoryItems requiredItemType = FPEInventoryManagerScript.eInventoryItems.APPLE;
        public FPEInventoryManagerScript.eInventoryItems RequiredItemType { get { return requiredItemType; } }

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("The quantity of inventory item required for the activation")]
        private int requiredInventoryQuantity = 1;
        public int RequiredInventoryQuantity {  get { return requiredInventoryQuantity; } }

        public enum eInventoryRequirementMode
        {
            IN_HAND = 0,
            IN_INVENTORY = 1,
            IN_HAND_OR_INVENTORY = 2 
        }

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("Specify how the inventory item must be in player's possession for activation. Things like keycards might be required to be in hand, whereas a secret password written down on a scrap of paper can be in inventory or in hand.")]
        private eInventoryRequirementMode requiredToBeInHand = eInventoryRequirementMode.IN_HAND_OR_INVENTORY;
        public eInventoryRequirementMode RequiredToBeInHand {  get { return requiredToBeInHand; } }

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If true, the activation will remove the item(s) once activation is triggered. (e.g. Remove battery when placed in radio. Don't remove keycard when swiped to open door.")]
        private bool removeOnUse = false;
        public bool RemoveOnUse {  get { return removeOnUse; } }

        [Header("Type of Activation and Events")]
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("This will dictate the nature of the events. ONCE: Will only fire the first time. EVERYTIME: Will fire on every activation.")]
        private FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType eventFireType = FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.ONCE;
        public FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType EventFireType {  get { return eventFireType; } }

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If using the EVERYTIME event fire type, set this time to some value (in seconds) which will suspend the interaction for that amount of time before the activation can be repeated. Not to be used as a replacement for complex state management.")]
        private float eventRepeatDelay = 0.0f;
        private float eventRepeatCounter = 0.0f;
        private string previousInteractionString = "";

        [Header("Shared 'Activation' and 'Toggle On' Event")]
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If specified, this event will fire on activation. It will adhere to defined occurrence type (e.g. fire once, fire every time, etc.)")]
        private FPEGenericEvent ActivationEvent;

        [Header("Shared 'Activation Failure' Event")]
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If specified, this event is fired when the player needs inventory to activate the object but does not have it. (e.g. beep and flash a 'keycard required' warning light)")]
        private FPEGenericEvent ActivationFailureEvent;

        [Header("TOGGLE-specific 'Toggle Off' Event")]
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If specified, this event will fire on de-activation or 'toggle off'.")]
        private FPEGenericEvent DeactivationEvent;

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If true, toggling object OFF will also adhere to inventory requirements above")]
        private bool toggleOffRequiresInventory = false;
        public bool ToggleOffRequiresInventory { get { return toggleOffRequiresInventory; } }

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("Overrides interaction string, and applied when toggle is currently OFF")]
        private string toggleOnInteractionString;
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("Overrides interaction string, and applied when toggle is currently ON")]
        private string toggleOffInteractionString;

        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If true, the toggle will toggle ON and fire the ToggleOnEvent when scene starts.")]
        private bool toggleOnAtStart = false;
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If true, the toggle will toggle OFF and fire the ToggleOnEvent when scene starts.")]
        private bool toggleOffAtStart = false;

        [Header("Save Game Options")]
        [SerializeField, Tooltip("If Event Fire Type is TOGGLE, and this value is true, the Toggle On and Toggle Off events will re-occur when game is loaded. For some objects like lights, a value of true is advised. For other objects like doors, a value of false makes more sense.")]
        private bool fireToggleEventsOnLoadGame = true;

        private bool toggleOn = false;
        public bool IsToggledOn { get { return toggleOn; } }

        private bool eventHasFiredOnce = false;

        public override void Awake()
        {

            base.Awake();
            interactionType = eInteractionType.ACTIVATE;
            // You may want to override assigned Inspector value for canInteractWithWhileHoldingObject in child classes, depending on the object and use case

            if (requireInventoryItem && requiredInventoryQuantity > 1 && requiredToBeInHand == eInventoryRequirementMode.IN_HAND)
            {
                Debug.LogError("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '"+gameObject.name+"' is configured to require more than one '"+requiredItemType+"' but also that the '"+ requiredItemType + "'s are in player's hand. Player can only activate with one object in hand at a time. This activation will not work correctly.", gameObject);
            }
            else if (requireInventoryItem && requiredInventoryQuantity > 1 && requiredToBeInHand == eInventoryRequirementMode.IN_HAND_OR_INVENTORY)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '" + gameObject.name + "' is configured to require more than one '" + requiredItemType + "' but also that the '" + requiredItemType + "'s are in either in player's hand or in inventory. Player can only activate with one object in hand at a time. This activation may not work as expected.", gameObject);
            }

            if(toggleOnAtStart && toggleOffAtStart)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '" + gameObject.name + "' has both Toggle On At Start and Toggle Off At Start set to true.");
            }

        }

        public override void Start()
        {

            base.Start();

            // Some sanity checks if the wrong checkboxes are checked
            if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.ONCE || eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.EVERYTIME)
            {

                if(DeactivationEvent.GetPersistentEventCount() != 0)
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Object '"+gameObject.name+"' is of fire type '"+ eventFireType + "', but has a DeactivationEvent specified. This event will not fire unless you use TOGGLE type.", gameObject);
                }

            }
            else if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.TOGGLE)
            {
                if (DeactivationEvent.GetPersistentEventCount() == 0)
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Object '" + gameObject.name + "' is of fire type 'TOGGLE', but has no DeactivationEvent specified. Consider using a different type.");
                }
            }

            if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.TOGGLE)
            {

                if (toggleOnAtStart)
                {
                    doToggleOn();
                }
                if(toggleOffAtStart)
                {
                    doToggleOff();
                }

            }

        }

        void Update()
        {

            if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.EVERYTIME && eventRepeatCounter > 0.0f)
            {

                eventRepeatCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

                if (eventRepeatCounter <= 0.0f)
                {
                    interactionString = previousInteractionString;
                }

            }

        }

        public override bool interactionsAllowedWhenHoldingObject()
        {
            return canInteractWithWhileHoldingObject;
        }

        public virtual void activate()
        {

            base.interact();

            if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.ONCE)
            {

                if (!eventHasFiredOnce)
                {

                    eventHasFiredOnce = true;

                    if (ActivationEvent != null)
                    {
                        ActivationEvent.Invoke();
                    }

                }

            }
            else if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.EVERYTIME)
            {

                if (ActivationEvent != null && eventRepeatCounter <= 0.0f)
                {

                    ActivationEvent.Invoke();

                    if (eventRepeatDelay > 0.0f)
                    {

                        eventRepeatCounter = eventRepeatDelay;
                        previousInteractionString = interactionString;
                        interactionString = "";

                    }

                }

            }
            else if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.TOGGLE)
            {

                if (toggleOn)
                {
                    doToggleOff();
                }
                else
                {
                    doToggleOn();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("FPEInteractableActivateGenericScript:: eventFireType '" + eventFireType + "' not yet implemented!");
            }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (ActivationEvent.GetPersistentEventCount() == 0)
            {
                Debug.LogError("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '" + gameObject.name + "' has no Activation Event assigned!", gameObject);
            }
#endif

        }

        public void failToActivate()
        {

            if(ActivationFailureEvent != null)
            {
                ActivationFailureEvent.Invoke();
            }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (ActivationFailureEvent.GetPersistentEventCount() == 0)
            {
                Debug.LogError("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '" + gameObject.name + "' has no Activation Failure Event assigned! If this was intentional, you can ignore this error.", gameObject);
            }
#endif

        }

        private void doToggleOn()
        {

            toggleOn = true;
            interactionString = toggleOffInteractionString;

            if (ActivationEvent != null)
            {
                ActivationEvent.Invoke();
            }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (ActivationEvent.GetPersistentEventCount() == 0)
            {
                Debug.LogError("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '" + gameObject.name + "' has no Activation Event assigned!", gameObject);
            }
#endif

        }

        private void doToggleOff()
        {

            toggleOn = false;
            interactionString = toggleOnInteractionString;

            if (DeactivationEvent != null)
            {
                DeactivationEvent.Invoke();
            }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (DeactivationEvent.GetPersistentEventCount() == 0)
            {
                Debug.LogError("FPEInteractableActivateScript:: Object '" + gameObject.name + "' has no Deactivation Event assigned!", gameObject);
            }
#endif

        }

        #region GAME_SAVE_LOAD

        public FPEActivateSaveData getSaveGameData()
        {

            // If we're in the middle of a repeat delay, save the previous interaction string so we don't load with a blank string :)
            string interactionStringToSave = (interactionString == "" ? previousInteractionString : interactionString);
            return new FPEActivateSaveData(gameObject.name, eventHasFiredOnce, toggleOn, interactionStringToSave);

        }

        public void restoreSaveGameData(FPEActivateSaveData data)
        {

            eventHasFiredOnce = data.FiredOnce;
            toggleOn = data.ToggleCurrentlyOn;
            interactionString = data.InteractionString;

            if (eventFireType == FPEGenericEvent.eEventFireType.TOGGLE && fireToggleEventsOnLoadGame)
            {

                if (toggleOn)
                {
                    doToggleOn();
                }
                else
                {
                    doToggleOff();
                }

            }

        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you disable a script it only disables functions like `Start`, `Update`, `FixedUpdate` etc. (See full list in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html?_ga=2.98626782.1565450746.1583529169-1417240115.1583529169)). See also [Behaviour.enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) which says:

> Enabled Behaviours are Updated, disabled Behaviours are not.
>   This is shown as the small checkbox in the inspector of the behaviour.

This means that if in another script you have:
`GetComponent<FPEInteractableActivateScript>().activate();` 
 `activate` will be called even if `FPEInteractableActivateScript` is disabled.
Also if you have `activate` set as a handler for a button it will also be invoked even if the script is disabled.

What you can do is guard with [Behaviour.isActiveAndEnabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-isActiveAndEnabled.html):

```
public virtual void activate()
{
    if(!isActiveAndEnabled) return;    
    ...
}
```

Or check if the gameobject is active/script is enabled before calling, in this example, activate.